# How do I show flip effect in flex viewstate?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, viewstack

I'm new to Flex.

I want to build cool web application in flex.

For displaying content of my site, I use viewstack and button bar. It is ready, but now I'd like to add some animation effect in that.

For example changing the navigation content shows flip animation.
So how do I do that?

Help full [link](http://www.flex-blog.com/flex-effects-example-in-a-viewstack/).

Comment: Going to learn [Flex effects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf5fdc3-7fff.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fb6)

Comment: Later [this](http://blog.flexexamples.com/category/effects/) and [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e4d.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf6475a-7ff9) had helped me.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to another question: [How can I nicely animate between viewstacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870622/how-can-i-nicely-animate-between-viewstacks).

Perhaps that will help?

Answer (score -2):

That example shows the most basic kind of animation which is readily available using open and widely supported web-standards such as HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. The [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/) will allow you to do this in just a few lines of code. Do you have an absolute requirement for flex?